# Working with large table in MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to do simple application in Java, that is supposed to insert data or read data from MySQL DB.

But what I'm facing is, that I'm not able to work fast with my table. Let's say I have table with two columns. First 'frst' is bigint unsigned unique and there is values from 1, 2, 3 .... 300 000 000. Second, let's call it 'result', is mediumint with values like 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2 ... 1, 3, 1 - for each 'frst'.

Well, and now, i have milions of records. Actually, the DB file have 19GB.

When I'm trying to run (select frst from table_name where result = 2), it takes very long time.

In my java application, I'm using JDBC and Statement / ResultSet for reading and PreparedStatement for inserting.

Could somebody tell me, how to work with large table like this? Thank you!!

Comment: add the code you already have

Comment: try to load records with `LIMIT` or check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp, because no user will need ALL data at once.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you will retrieve a lot of entries expect the query to take some time to retrieve all the entries. You may consider some pagination of the results, in order to improve the user experience.

Second, what you could do to improve the performance of your query is to create an index like:

```
create index my_idx on table_name(result, frst);
```

See mysql [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) for more details.

Comment: Dan, thank you for advice. I'm going to definitly try it. What I'm thinking on right now is, that if I try to fetch, lets say, 300000000 values of type BigInt, which is 8b per value, ResultSet mush handle 300000000*8bytes, which is 2.4GB. This is propably the problem why is it slow. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you are retrieving a lot of data the performance is degraded. Like I mentioned you should retrieve the data in pages (using mysql limit) or if you need to compute something with the values, per `result` or per `frst`, like sum, avg, min, max or other aggregate functions, you should compute them in sql, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the data in the table, you might want to push some logic to the database (like count, max, min, average, ...) since they were built to handle big amounts of data. In addition to that this will also reduce the traffic between your database and your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could try indexing the columns that you are working on which will make them faster to search on.

```
CREATE INDEX yourIndexName
ON YOUR_TABLE_NAME(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME);
```

Just be aware that this can cause performance to slow when updating or inserting new records as the index has to be updated/inserted too. For more info refer to [here](http://odetocode.com/articles/237.aspx)